# Data is being duplicated in the div

Tags: jquery

Please see the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/NLe3s/

If only one horizontal tab is clicked on then its behaving fine .

But If i click on multiple horizontal tabs , the data is being duplicated in the div .

please see the picture here

[image]

Please tell me how to eliminate that ??

On click of the horizontal tab  , i am appending data to the div this way .

```
$("#tab-dock").append('<div id="daccordion" />');

$("#daccordion").append('<h3><a href="#">Info</a></h3>')
    .append('<div id="dinfo"></div>')
    .append('<h3><a href="#">Market</a></h3>')
    .append('<div id="dmarket"></div>');

$("#daccordion").accordion({
    activate: function (event, ui) {

        setStuff(event, ui);
    },
    heightStyle: "content",
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    clearStyle: true,
    active: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLe3s/1/)

Just add

```
$('#daccordion').remove();
```

right *before*

```
$("#tab-dock").append('<div id="daccordion" />');
```

**OR** Another way could be

```
$("#tab-dock").html('<div id="daccordion" />');
```

Which is simply to write and you don't have to add more code lines.

You can do a better check to avoid duplicate divs with the same id ( which is, of course, wrong )

Answer (score 1):

Remove html inside the div before appending new html like this:

```
$("#tab-dock").html("");
```

then:

```
$("#tab-dock").append('<div id="daccordion" />');

$("#daccordion").append('<h3><a href="#">Info</a></h3>')
    .append('<div id="dinfo"></div>')
    .append('<h3><a href="#">Market</a></h3>')
    .append('<div id="dmarket"></div>');
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/acYk7/)

Comment: What is best solution , either removing it completely or emptying it ??

Comment: both will do the job ``.html("")`` will remove all html inside it whatever it is,but ``remove()`` will not work if id changed or if you append span instead of div

Comment: It's up to you @user3674364. It's the same

Comment: @EhsanSajjad doin `$('#daccordion')` will target both divs or spans with that ID. No difference.

Comment: It is same but i mentioned what are limitations in remove for remove you need to pass element which one to remove

Comment: @KevinCittadini i mean to say if id changed or element changed

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It's up to the user and to his needs. There're no absolute "best" or "worst" in this case. Changing id, changing the target are things that we ( giving advices ) should not worry too much about unless is clearly asked

Comment: Thank you very much , ya i see that both are excellent solutions , thanks once again .

Comment: @KevinCittadini see my first comment i said that already that both do same job but both have some pros and cons..:)